# RoR: How to sort an array with the help of scopes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an array `@products`. Each element of the array is a hash, containing a few fields (but not all) from `Product` table and the corresponding values.

I have a scope `descend_by_popularity` in `Product` which allows me to sort the products based on `popularity` field. I'd like to sort the array `@products` using this scope.

What I tried:

```
@product_group = Array.new
@products.each do |product|
    @product_group.push(Product.find(product['id']))
end
@product_group1 = @product_group.descend_by_popularity
```

But this gives me error:

```
undefined method `descend_by_popularity' for #<Array:0xb2497200>
```

I also want to change the sorted `Product` list back to the format of `@products` array.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scopes only make sense within the ActiveRecord context for requests to the database (since it is used to change the SQL query). What you did is throwing a lot of products into an array. This array then knows nothing about the scope anymore. You would have to use the scope when you create the @products object. (and it does not seem to make a lot of sense to move the result of a query into an array)

So something like

```
@products = Product.descend_by_popularity.where(some more stuff)
```

should work for you. After that you should have the records in the order defined by the scope and can then either use them directly or still push them into an array if that's what you want to do.

With the updated info from the comments it looks like maybe the best way to go would be to first collect only the Product ids from the solr response into an array and then run that as search together with your scope:

```
@product_group = @products.map{|product| product.id}
@result = Product.where(id: @product_group).descend_by_popularity
```

this should technically work, peformance is a different question. I would consider aggregating this data into the Solr document, if it doesn't change too often.

Now assuming you are only interested in the order of products as such, you could do something like this to get @products into this order:

```
@result.map{|r| @products.find{|p| p[:id] == r.id}
```

though this may slow down things a bit.

Comment: I am fetching the `@products` array from `solr`. So, its not possible to change the it.

Comment: Then you must either use Solr for sorting (faster anyway) or manually sort. How does this scope actually look? If it's only on one or two fields you could use Array#sort (depending how large this array can get this may or may not work.)

Comment: Its not possible to add the field to solr. The scope is `lambda{
      {
        :joins => :master,
        :order => <<SQL
           COALESCE((
             SELECT
               COUNT(line_items.id)
             FROM
               line_items
             JOIN
               variants as popular_variants
             ON
               popular_variants.id = line_items.variant_id
             WHERE
               popular_variants.product_id = products.id
           ), 0) DESC
SQL
      }
    }`

Comment: @products has 1,000 products while Product has 10,000

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. There is one issue though, I'd like to have the array back in the response and not `Products`. How can i map the `Product`s to the format of the array?

Comment: I do not exactly understand what you want to do? Technically the `Products` you get in @result behaves like an Array for most cases. If you must have an array you can always use map like `@result.map{|p| p}`. (or what exactly do you understand with 'format of the array'?)

Comment: `@result` would be an array but of `Product` objects. I am working with an array(@products) with a format different from that of `Product` table. To be able to render the views correctly, I want to retain the format.

Comment: Well, you can always do some merging. Point is, that `@result` is now  ordered, so you would have to use it as the base and then find the right item in `@products`. How this would be done best would depend on what information you want to use from `@results` (if any but the order).

Comment: Thanks a lot for you help. :). Quite an elegant solution

Comment: I added a way to get the `@products` array into sort order, assuming you ignore other fields from the result.

Comment: `@result.map{|r| @products.find{|p| p[:id] == r.id}` doesn't quite change the order of `@products`. It remains the same

Comment: Hmm, it should generate a new array with all the elements from products, now in the new order (`@products` itself stays the same).

Comment: No, I meant order remains the same. The order didn't change

Comment: if you do `@foo = @result.map{|r| @products.find{|p| p[:id] == r.id}` then @foo has the same order as `@products`?

Comment: Does tis work for you or is it mandatory to have `@products` sorted?

Answer (score 0):

Try this: find_by_id as params

```
@product_group = Array.new

@products.each do |product|
   @product_group.push(Product.find(params['id']))
end
```

and return the array of @product_group

```
@product_group1 = @product_group.descend_by_popularity
```

Comment: This won't work. params['id'] would be none. can't find `Product` without an id

Comment: what is in your params ?, This is your controller level code or model level.?